# Plurals in search terms

Tags: feature-request, search

Not sure if this has been covered on another meta site, but I'd like to see the site's search facility handle plurals or word stemming.

While looking for questions on podcasts, I searched for 'podcast' and got only results containing the literal word 'podcast'.  Searching for 'podcasts' hit the gold, [this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/48/which-brewing-podcasts-do-you-listen-to).

The problem may be specific to this site's large amount of "non-standard" terms, but would be handy to see some basic [depluralisation rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dmitryr/archive/2007/01/11/simple-english-noun-pluralizer-in-c.aspx) applied, if feasible.

Comment: You'll probably need to put in a request with Atwood or ask about that on meta.stackexchange.com.   I don't think we've got the ability to alter those sorts of mechanisms.

Comment: Perhaps a moderator could shunt this question over to that site, in stead of retyping.

Comment: Asking here is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange has [recently modified](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/) its search functionality on the sites, however, [the de facto Stack Overflow home page is meant to be a web search](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/search-all-stack-exchange-sites/).

When you search, notice the sidebar:

[image: sidebar search help]

On that page, notice the emphasis on popular search engines:

[image: popular search engines]

Subsequently, notice the top results:

[image: first result for 'podcast']